# Printing only the value and excluding null

Tags: text-processing, json, jq, null

I'm trying to print the json output using jq, But I'm getting null 
How can I print only access_key and secret_key, but not `null`?

```
$ cat sample.json | jq '.'

{
  "access_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
{
  "secret_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

$ cat sample.json | jq -e ".access_key"  
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
null
```

The same happens with secret_key.

If I use "raw output", I get an error:

```
$ cat sample.json | jq -r ".access_key" | jq --raw-output 'select(type == "string")'
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
```

I tried this also:

```
$ cat sample.json | jq -re ".access_key" | jq 'select(.go != null) | .geo' > geo-only.json
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input is not valid json.  You can use https://jsonlint.com to check.

You could make it valid by changing it to something like:

```
[{
    "access_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}, {
    "secret_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}]
```

Or `jq` has a workaround for this:

```
cat sample.json | jq "..|objects|select(.access_key) | .access_key"
```

I recommend using a tool simply called [json](https://github.com/trentm/json) over jq.  It's not as fast but it's much more intuitive to use and has better features.

json handles this with the `-g` argument:

> -g, --group
>
> > Group adjacent objects into an array of objects, or concatenate adjacent arrays into a single array.

```
$ cat sample.json | json -ag access_key
1234
```

Answer (score 0):

a solution is to use `empty`

```
cat sample.json | jq -r -e ".access_key // empty "
```